# How to call a Java method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

How do you call a Java method/ function from Javascript?

Java Function:

```
class Javafunction{

   public static void main(String[] args){

       System.out.println("It Works!");


   }
}
```

Javascript Function:

```
  function CallJavafunction() {
    
    Javafunction()

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run java method in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524061/how-to-run-java-method-in-react-native)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: @user3840170, applets are deprecated since 2017

Comment: @Sam So what? If that’s what the asker wants…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call java code from javascript in your react-native app, you have to create a module

I suggest reading the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Java code - android/app/src/main/java/com/your-app-name/JavaModule.java

```java
package com.your-app-name; // replace com.your-app-name with your app’s name
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JavaModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
   JavaModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
       super(context);
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return "JavaModule";
   }

   @ReactMethod
   public void Javafunction(){
       System.out.println("It Works!");
   }
}
```

Register the Module - android/app/src/main/java/com/your-app-name/MyAppPackage.java

```java
package com.your-app-name; // replace your-app-name with your app’s name
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {

   @Override
   public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       return Collections.emptyList();
   }

   @Override
   public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
           ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

       modules.add(new JavaModule(reactContext));

       return modules;
   }

}
```

To register the package change the getPackages method in this file: android/app/src/main/java/com/your-app-name/MainApplication.java

```java
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    // below MyAppPackage is added to the list of packages returned
    packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
    return packages;
}
```

JavaScript code

```js
const { JavaModule } = ReactNative.NativeModules;
JavaModule.Javafunction();
```

Comment: Thanks but I´m getting the error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'JavaModule.Javafunction')

What is wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add an important step. Edited my answer to add that. You have to change the getPackages method in MainApplication.java

Comment: Its working now;)
How do you call a Variable Value from the JavaModule Class in the React Native?

var c = NativeModules.JavaModule.Javafunction().d; gives me: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.JavaModule.Javafunction().d')


var c = NativeModules.JavaModule.Javafunction.d; gives me: undefined

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do this But you can Calling Java code from a JavaScript adapter

Here Is the Example and documentation : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mpf/8.0.0?topic=code-calling-java-from-javascript-adapter